# How to get the instrument dictionary in JFugue 5.0

Tags: java, midi, jfugue

I'm doing a project with JFugue 5.0, I've tried 4.0 but 5.0 seems smoother than his previous brother. Anyway, I have the complete guide to JFugue v4 and these are the Strings used to refer to the [differents percussion instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXfaI.png)

Now, when I try to run my code I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: JFugue NoteSubparser: Could not find 'HIGH_TOM' in dictionary.
```

And this is my custom Rhythm Map I use:

```
kitPercusion = new HashMap<>();
    kitPercusion.put('O', "[ACOUSTIC_BASS_DRUM]i");
    kitPercusion.put('S', "[ACOUSTIC_SNARE]i");
    kitPercusion.put('`', "[CLOSED_HI_HAT]s Rs");
    kitPercusion.put('^', "[OPEN_HI_HAT]i");
    kitPercusion.put('R', "[RIDE_CYMBAL_1]s Rs");
    kitPercusion.put('C', "[CRASH_CYMBAL_1]s Rs");
    kitPercusion.put('T', "[HIGH_TOM]s Rs");
    kitPercusion.put('-', "[HI_MID_TOM]s Rs");
    kitPercusion.put('_', "[LOW_FLOOR_TOM]s Rs");
    kitPercusion.put('~', "[COWBELL]i");
    kitPercusion.put('.', "Ri");
```

In the official web examples I've seen that the names have been "simplified" like "guitar", "piano" and so on.

Is there a way to get the dictionary with the valid instrument Strings?

**EDIT**:
I have tried this, but it prints an empty Map

```
    Player player = new Player();
    StaccatoParser sp = player.getStaccatoParser();
    StaccatoParserContext spc = new StaccatoParserContext(sp);
    System.out.println(spc.getDictionary());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the percussion instruments are held in the static String[]  `Note.PERCUSSION_NAMES`.

`HI_TOM` is what you're looking for. In JFugue 5, all of the percussion instruments formerly named `HIGH_X` or `LOW_X` have been simplified to `HI_X` or `LO_X`.

(You might also be interested in instrument names, which are different from percussion names. Percussion names are simply alternate names for note values intended for use when those notes are played in the 10th channel (`V9`), which MIDI reserves for percussion instruments (this is the reason why your MIDI piano has percussion symbols over several of the notes); instrument names are for actual instrument patches. You can find those in `MidiDictionary.INSTRUMENT_BYTE_TO_STRING` and `MidiDictionary.INSTRUMENT_STRING_TO_BYTE`.)

Comment: David Koelle himself has answered! Thank you very much.

Comment: That's one of the nice things about StackOverflow - lots of comments and answers from the original authors of stuff!